# AWS Lights DNS Zone Setup

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I currently have an application server on AWS Lightsail that serving smartphone app. I had to make backend changes mostly security tweaks to secure API calls between the server and the app. The changes are still in my test server and the moment i apply them to production current users wont be able to communicate with the server. They will be logged out and required to update the app before login again. My problem is I cant really find a way to avoid service disruption and there will be downtime between the time I deploy the changes until my app update gets approved by Apple as Apple need a running server to test the app before they approve it. during that time my users who are using the old version wont be able to communicate with the updated server and that time would be 1-2 days which is something I cant afford.

My questions:

1. First Question

Is there anyway I can have DNS Zone setup and have both the old and new servers running and direct traffic coming from the old and updated app to the respective server? I have an initial thought that this can be done by using Route 53 however, i am not sure how to get this working.

2. Second Question
   Do I need add a config file to the updated app to check the health of the server and communicate with accordingly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have two app versions that need two different servers, why would you not use two different hostnames, e.g  `app.example.com` and `appv2.example.com`?  It's not clear how your second question is related to the first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue add different hostname to the new app, we can change it once the app is released by apple. Do you think if we add both hostnames to the new app once is primary and the other is secondry and have a failover would fix the issue?

Comment: Why change it later?  Why not just continue to use the new one?  New app, new back-end, new hostname.

Comment: So how about existing users? they have app.example.com hardcoded to the app, and once the new app is release we will have two different hostnames and we cant point two hostnames into the same server. new backend wont work with the old app.

Comment: *"we cant point two hostnames into the same server"*  Yes, you can.  There is no limit to the number of hostnames that you can point to a single server.